# Show Git subtree commit history when --squash option was used

Tags: git, git-log, git-subtree, subtree, git-history

Is there any way to show only subtree history, like with `git log` but filtering only specific subtree's related commits?

When I add a subtree with `--squash` option only a merge commit is shown, but the subtree history is still somewhere, since I can split and push it as standalone repository with its complete history.

How can I see that apparently hidden history when `--squash` option is used?

Comment: I would start with `git log --graph path/to/subdirectory`, is there something that doesn't fit your use case here ?

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks, but that kind of commands doesn't work when the subdirectory is a subtree generated with `--squash` option. It doesn't show the subtree history previous its creation.

Comment: ok, iirc `git subtree` also stores some information in the commit message. Check if `git show <last commit on subtree>` tells you which sha to look for in the origin repository.